# Control by jquery if an overflow-x occurs through conditionals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been searching and I don't know if I am searching badly or there is not much information. I would like to know if it can be controlled when an X axis overflow occurs from javascript / jquery.

Basically what happens to me is that I have a series of tables that depending on the data, this can overflow on the X axis and when this happens I want to change the behavior of this using a Boolean variable.

My question is, can you apply an `if else` conditional that controls overflow? Something like that,

```
if (table_overflow-x == True){
    var myBoolVar == True;
}else{
    var myBoolVar == False;
}
```

Or

```
var myBoolVar = False;
if (table_overflow-x == True){
    myBoolVar == True;
}
```

I know I don't put my code, but I don't know how to do it, or really if it can be done (I guess it can be done).

**Edit:**

Thinking more about this, can be done knowing the size of the screen and my window?

Regards, and thank you very much!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can declare `variable` before (outside) your if statement as `undefined`, and set the value inside your if statement.

Comment: What variable? What I want to do is, if I don't have overflow my boolean will be false if the table grows and overflows , change my boolean variable to true that will activate some functions.

Comment: You literally have a variable named `variable` in your code sample. That is the variable i am talking about.

Comment: Haha, ok. Yes this one (now I edited the name).